# Different flow in the Android Activity Stack?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a set of activities A, B, C.

The user can go A->B->C->B->C->B. I don't want B and C to be repeating like this. Is there any intent flag I can set to limit this to A->B->C so that the user doesn't have to press the back button many times?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT).

Answer (score 0):

Add following attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml. You should add this attribute to each activity's block, which you want to initialize only once and preserve it's state during application lifetime:

```
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

And use following sample of code to switch between activities:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```

You also can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, but launchMode should be set to "singleTask" too.